# Query MySQL table based on form post

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a web form that allows the user to conduct a zip code search.  My intent is to use the form post to search a MySQL table for the matching zip code then return content from an associated field in the same row.

I can get as far as... form submits and directs user to the intended form_post.php page.  If I enter `<?php echo $_POST["zipcode"]; ?>` on the page it returns the content submitted by the user.

I followed the PHP/MySQLi examples from these pages:

```
http://www.w3schools.com
/php/php_mysql_connect.asp
/php/php_mysql_select.asp
/php/php_if_else.asp
```

I am able to connect to the database and return the 2 selected values from the table.  This is my example so far:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "db_username";
$password = "db_password";
$dbname = "db_name";

if (isset($_POST['zipcode'])) {
   $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT zip_code, area FROM zipcode_table WHERE zip_code = $zipcode";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Result: " . $row["zip_code"]. " " . $row["area"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

After the query returns the associated values I would like to determine if the returned value from 'area' is one of 3 values then forward the user to the appropriate url.

I was working on an if/else statement as follows then got stuck.

```
if($result == "A") {
   header("Location: http://example.com/page-1/");
}  
  elseif($result == "B") {
   header("Location: http://example.com/page-2/");
}  
  elseif($result == "C") {
   header("Location: http://example.com/page-3/");
} else {
   header("Location: http://example.com/");
   exit();
}
```

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Are u gettign any errors ?

Comment: I would get a blank page if there was a typo.  Alternately I would get redirected to the example.com page where the form is located.  I tried to set it up like that in case someone typed "9999".

Comment: What are you trying to do here `if($result == "A")` ? Coz the type of `$result` will be an object so you cant compare that to a string and get `true`

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.  "A" would be one of 3 possible values from the 'area' field returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `$result` in if but, you not assign it area region.So, first relpace this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Result: " . $row["zip_code"]. " " . $row["area"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

with this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Result: " . $row["zip_code"]. " " . $row["area"]. "<br>";
        $result = $row["area"];
        break;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
    $result = "";
}
```

then replace query:

```
$sql = "SELECT zip_code, area FROM zipcode_table WHERE zip_code = $zipcode";
```

with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT zip_code, area FROM zipcode_table WHERE zip_code = '$zipcode'";
```

then your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for the typo.  I was trying to substitute everything out from my live version and missed that.